# How to reset my filter options to their initial blank state? React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some input boxes, select drop down, and date picker that are not being reset like I thought they would. Let's start with the input box and select drop down. Here is their code:

```
                <StyledInput
                  onChange={handleSearchChange}
                  value={searchText}
                  placeholder={"Search..."}
                />
                  <SelectDropDown
                    isClearable={false}
                    isSearchable={false}
                    strict={true}
                    allowInvalid={false}
                    getOptionLabel={opt => opt.name}
                    getOptionValue={opt => opt.value}
                    value={searchOptions.find(opt => opt.value === searchCol)}
                    options={searchOptions}
                    onChange={value => {
                      handleColSelect(value);
                    }}
                  />
```

Notice the handleSearchChange and handleColSelect:

```
 const handleColSelect = value => {
    setSearchCol(value.value);
  };

  const handleSearchChange = event => {
    setSearchText(event.target.value);
  };
```

I have a button that I want to reset these to their initial states (i.e. get rid of text in the input box, and reset the SelectDropDown).

I've tried doing so:

```
  const clearFilters = () => {
    setSearchText(undefined);
    setStartDate(undefined);
    setEndDate(undefined);
    setSearchCol(undefined);
  };
```

And in my button, simply this:

```
            <GreenOutlineButton
              onClick={() => {
                clearFilters();
              }}
            >
              Clear Filters
            </GreenOutlineButton>
```

There is another part to this to remove the queryParams that are set, and my button does so- however, it does not take away the text or reset the dropdown. Any ideas here?

Comment: Can you show me the code of `setSearchText` and others?

Comment: And try to use `""` or `null` instead of `undefined`

Comment: @IhsanFajarRamadhan the setSearchText can be found under "handleSearchChange" and others. I wonder if that's causing my issue for some reason. And setting to null or "" doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, setSearchText("") should work fine. For the SelectDropDown, you need to add one more entry to the options which will be your default entry. You can do this as follows:

```
options={[...searchOptions,{label:"Placeholder", value: null}]}
```

Then, inside clearFilters, use:

```
setSearchCol(null)
```

This should give you the desired result. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Oh. Can you share the repo?